# Android Seekbar with two thumbs

Tags: android, range, seekbar

Variations of this question can be found all over the internet but not an answer.

I want a seekbar with two-thumb range selection. I'm willing to program this myself but I lack experience with Android. Could someone give me some pointers on where to start. I mean, I know I will have to extend something (ProgressBar probably), but how should I go about to do that? Do I really have to recreate all the functionality of a standard seekbar, or is there an easier way?

Complete solutions are also welcome of course ;)

Comment: Why not try extending SeekBar itself or perhaps AbsSeekBar? THis is the source for SeekBar...http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/SeekBar.java you could look at that and AbsSeekBar source to see what it takes to add and handle a second thumb.

Comment: Hello MisterSquonk, I tried that but it is very complex to extend/ modify AbsSeekBar, I already create my own control using ImageView. It's very easy and simple

Comment: fully customize seekbar http://codingsignals.com/crystal-range-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I too was  looking for this, to no avail. So I made a new widget, feel free to use it: https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar

[image: Screenshot of RangeSeekBar]

Comment: this one is awesome! It would be even more awesome if the start and end could be reversed and if it would maintain state (loaded from Preferences or something)

Comment: Anything like this but extending normal SeekBar?

Comment: Thank you very much for allowing us to use this.  I did have a question on how to get it on the layout though.  In your example you had `
// add RangeSeekBar to pre-defined layout
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(<your-layout-id>);
layout.addView(seekBar);` but I wasn't sure how to get the viewgroup in the layout.  Can you give an example of how to set the view in the layout?  Thank you!  (This really came out jumbled.. I apologize)

Comment: @Brandon The example was meant to be as generic as possible. ViewGroup is a superclass of most layouts. Replace it with a specific layout of your choice - e.g. RelativeLayout.

Comment: Stephan, later on in the evening I realized that is probably what you intended with the view group and not the actual item.  Thank you for the quick response though!

Comment: @StephanTittel, Thanks for your answer.it is working fine but i have one issue,time gap between the min n max value is 3.when time gap equals 3,range seek bar sliders are not moving to gether.how to do this?In my case both sliders not cross over.

Comment: Fully customize seek bar with two way http://codingsignals.com/crystal-range-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: The link now goes to a "Google Code Archive" page. The source page is blank, the downloads page too. Does anyone have a copy of the code?

Comment: @user3175580 it has been moved to https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar; I will edit the post.

Comment: RangeSeekbar is a 1000-line abomination of terrible code and poor performance and should not be used.

Comment: This library doesn't seem to build correctly anymore. Also deprecated. I don't know why.

Answer (score 27):

"I too was looking for this, to no avail. So I made a new widget, feel free to use it: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/"

This example Stephan linked works great!
However, the user has to press any of the thumbs to get a respons. I wanted that if the user pressed the bar, the closest thumb would move to that position and work like normal.

I implemented this in the example code like this:

```
private final Thumb getClosestThumb(float touchX)

{
    double xValue = screenToNormalized(touchX);        
    return (Math.abs(xValue - normalizedMinValue) < Math.abs(xValue - normalizedMaxValue)) ? Thumb.MIN : Thumb.MAX;
}
```

And in the "`public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`",

```
if(pressedThumb == null),
   pressedThumb = getClosestThumb(mDownMotionX);
```

Comment: @StephanTittel, I have tried to do the same. please add this answer in your project, so no one will face issue like me.thanks for this.

Comment: Quite old post. I have one doubt. I wish the min value to be incremented or decremented everytime be 10. How to acheive that?

Comment: This component is a 1000-line abomination of terrible code and poor performance and should not be used.

Answer (score 3):

A windowed seek bar with left and right icons.
Presettable minimum window size and automatic anti crossover.

[image: Screenshot of windowed-seek-bar]

Mercurial repository at https://bitbucket.org/nimbusgb/windowed-seek-bar

Answer (score 2):

I have used the  anothem/android-range-seek-bar library

https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar

In xml

```
<org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/pricebar_with_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            rsb:absoluteMinValue="20"
            rsb:absoluteMaxValue="150"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
```

[image]

Comment: Add this sample in README pls :)

Comment: how to remove the label min / max ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati add this property rsb:showLabels="false"

Comment: This component is a 1000-line abomination of terrible code and poor performance and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Incase you are using any of the material components such as: `Snackbar, BottomNavigationView` etc. you don't have to use another 3rd party library.

The material library also ships with [RangeSlider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/RangeSlider) which can be used to select a range of values.

*Material library* *- **implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:latestVersion'***