# Creating own "SeekBar"

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, android-canvas

I want to create my own kind of a SeekBar which means I want to have for example two horizontal-sliders on a plot.

How can I do this? I just managed to bind a class to my view which draws a plot, but how can I put two sliders on it? I was thinking about putting a new layer on the plot and set a move-listener to it but have no idea how to do this. Or should I redraw the slider each time the user moves it?

The SeekBar is just for testing purpose. What I want is a slider on the plot:

[image: the SeekBar is just for testing purpose. What I want is a slider on the plot]

Comment: I am sure you want to implement ZoomIn/out functinality based on the seekbar scroll movement. Is it so?

Comment: no. each value is based on a certain location, so i have to move the map to the right point. the seekbar above is able to do it. my problem is the UI: how i can create my own "PlotSeekBar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this question: [Android Seekbar with two thumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795773/android-seekbar-with-two-thumbs). Android doesn't have a standard UI control but you should be able to find third-party source code.