# Android Two Thumbs Seekbar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am a beginner in android development and would like to create a custom seekbar with two thumbs (not the range bar version).

My goal is to achieve something like this:
[two thumbs seekbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCCVS.png)
The red thumb cannot be greater than the yellow.

I found this article which seems to be a good starting point, however I don't understand how to make the thumbs moving around. Only the textviews are changing as I slide my fingers.
http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-seek-bar-with-two-thumb.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795773/android-seekbar-with-two-thumbs

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar.

Answer (score 0):

For Making Below image type SeekBar,

[image]

Visit Here.
https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/