# How to make a vertical range seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

I have a application which needs a vertical range seekbar which has two thumbs for adjusting the position.I have no idea how to make a one. Please help me out..
Similar to this seekbar.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a working vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892179/how-can-i-get-a-working-vertical-seekbar-in-android)

Comment: @iamgopal Its not a duplicate answer .please check the image .I need a seekbar with two thumbs so that i can select the range manually.

Comment: you have edited your question. It's still a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/q/5795773/2550246

Comment: Your screenshot is from [this open source library](https://github.com/ITheBK/RangeBarVertical). "I have no idea how to make a one" -- you could read the source code for [the open source library](https://github.com/ITheBK/RangeBarVertical) from which you copied your image.

Comment: @iamgopal. Is there any link for vertical seekbar with two thumbs?

Comment: Here you go [link](https://github.com/ITheBK/RangeBarVertical/blob/master/rangebarvertical/src/main/java/com/opalox/rangebarvertical/RangeBarVertical.java)

Comment: @CommonsWare. The code is not working . APP is keep on crashing . Its suggesting me there is a issue with class  in the library .

Comment: Then ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve]. This would include the complete Java stack trace associated with your crash, along with the layout and Java code that cause the crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay .Will close this question .Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok I found this library:

https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

```
<com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar
        android:id="@+id/rb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="90"
        app:tickCount="16"
         />
```

int left_index = rb.getLeftIndex();

int right_index = rb.getRightIndex();

hope it will be usefull

Comment: I Dont want a simple vertical seekbar . i need a seekbar with two thumbs .so that i can select the range .Please refer the image

Comment: try my last edit

Comment: great This is the perfect solution @abhi20392